# PHP MYSQLI Database query not returning string after an apostrophe

Tags: php, database, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have a PHP search function that is not returning string characters after an apostrophe eg. (Golden State's Garden) will return (Golden State). The code I'm using is below. I have search for an answer but it seems most responses have commented on escaping a string. I have the information in the database already and trying to retreive it with the query, the code is

```
if (isset($_POST["search_submit"]))  {

    if(empty(trim($_POST["search"]))){
        echo 'Please search for an item';
    } else{
        $find = "%".(trim($_POST["search"]))."%";
        $sql = ("SELECT * FROM combine WHERE a_product 
                    LIKE ? OR b_product LIKE ? ");
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
           echo "connection failed, try again later";
        }else{
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $find, 
                $find);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);


if(!empty($_SESSION['basket'])){ 
        foreach($_SESSION['basket'] as $key => $value){ 
    <tr>  
       <td><?php echo $value["name"]; ?></td>
```

Comment: The code looks fine, can you show code which demonstrates where the string is truncated, is it just being displayed incorrectly (try `print_r()` on the row being retrieved from the database)

Comment: A var_dump shows  string(8) "football" when the whole string should be "football's and baskekball's". All other strings not containing an apostrophe gets returned in full

Comment: I have a foreach loop as $key=>$value and echoing out a result. Only result that is affected are one's containing apostrophes

Comment: Can you add the code for that loop?

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
$find="%".mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['search'])."%";
```

It will get the full string result you want.

Comment: There is an error, it is saying that mysqli_real_escape_string expects 2 parameters, only 1 given. When I try to add $conn to the code it echos connection failed

Comment: $find = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['search']);

Comment: and then you can use the  $find="%".$find."%";

Comment: you can check your connection variable properly $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","your_mysqluser","yourmysql_psw","your mysql_db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

Comment: Your code works, thank you. But I think what is causing the problem is after the initial search where the string comes out in full I have another code that collects that information and puts it into another field where I have this snippet, if(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'id')){
    if(isset($_SESSION['basket'])), I think this is where the string breaks down, maybe it's the filter_input that is breaking the string